# HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA empty - alternate solution

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a script that is provided by an E-commerce site that obtains data from an XML feed that is posted to a URL on my site.  The script gathers the data using....

```
$requestBodyXML = new DOMDocument();

# Load the request body into XML and check that the result has been parsed into XML
if ($requestBodyXML->loadXML($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) == true)
```

The problem is that there's no data being passed.  I understand this is depreciated, but how else would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` [requires an ini value to be set](http://in.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data), using the input stream should work without any special ini settings and is also the 'prefered' method. It is worth noting that neither `php://input` or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

```
//The alternative method
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input')
```

[Documentation](http://in.php.net/wrappers.php)